# How to create image set for both landscape and portrait orientation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm new in iOS programming. I want to create image set for background image of login view in my application (iPhone, iPad). I prepared images for portrait orientation, and for landscape orientation. But I don't know how to setup image set.

Comment: Can you share an example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `assets` for images. you can use size classed for different images for portrait and landscape. For, example if you want to set images for all `iphones` in portrait then you should select `compact width and regular height` size class and you can set all your portrait images there. So, you can set your images as per size class if you have different images for different orientation. If you have common image then no need to set it for different size class you can set it as universal.